# How to delete some user data using Firebase admin sdk?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I need to remove only part of data in user section by key

```py
ref = db.reference(user.uid)
user_data = ref.get()
reqs = user_data['support_req']

for req in reqs:
  print(req)
  print(user_data['support_req'][req])
```

result:

```
-NQKyF9j6Fcnd4aeQyW5

{'telephone': '+000000000000'}
```

I need to remove key and value from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete all the RTDB nodes under the `support_req` node, the following should do the trick (untested):

```
support_req_ref = db.reference(user.uid + '/support_req')
support_req_ref.delete()
```

If you want to delete a specific sub-node of the user's `support_req` node you need to know its id, e.g. `-NQKyF9j6Fcnd4aeQyW5` in your example. Then you should do:

```
support_req_ref = db.reference(user.uid + '/support_req/-NQKyF9j6Fcnd4aeQyW5')
support_req_ref.delete()
```